# TFS2008 select agent build from VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, build

I would like to be able to select the build agent to use to deploy my web application. When the code is being built for testing I would like for it to use a certain build agent and deploy to our test server and when the code is being built for production I would like for it to use another build agent and deploy it to our production server, Automatically! Does anyone have experience in doing this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by tweeking my ports and using MSDeploy